# Netlogo. How to sum the variable(turtle own) of one turtle to another turtle

Tags: netlogo

In my program there is a turtle which has the variable biomass ( turtle own biomass). In the word is possible to have a lot of turtles with different biomass.  What i  need to: 
When a turtle found another in the same patch they must transfer their biomass(sum the biomass of all turtles ) to the turtle whose biomass is higher and then turn their(all turtle in the patch except the one whose biomass is higher) biomass to zero. ( there is a command that kills the turtle with zero biomass already)
I thank you for the attention!

Hey! I tried to do my own code as you said me to do. 
But the code only works in the begin of the program. As the program will running some case bug the program. I dont know where is this bug comming from.... The variable starts to sum it self... This is the part of the code:
biomass is a variable from the turtle   >  turtle-own [biomass]

```
while [any? Other turtles-here]
[
    Let maximum max[biomass] of turtles-here
    Let auxi  sum[biomass]of turtles-here
    Let higher turtles-here with-max[biomass]
    Let otherhigher count other turtles-here with-max [ biomass]
    If (otherhigher>0)
    [set higher turtles-here with-max[headling] ; (I PUT THIS IN CASE THE TURTLE HAS THE SAME BIOMASS]
     Ask higher [ set biomas (aux) ]
     Let lower turtles-here with [biomass< maximum]  ; (LOWER CAN BE MORE THAN ONE)
     Ask lower [set biomass (0)]
     Ask turtles-here with [biomass<=0] [die]
    ]
    end
```

Comment: Maybe you want to try to find a solution by yourself first. Here are some useful primitives you would need. I would suggest you look them up in the NetLogo dictionary:
'if, any?, other, turtles-here, max-one-of, sum'. If you need further help I could also post a solution, but I think you would learn a lot less than developing it on your own.

Comment: Hey, im posting my code in the question! but stlil doesnt work

Comment: You can of course use a while loop, but in NetLogo there are more elegant ways. I assume the problem lies within the while loop and situations where there are 2 turtles on the same patch, but your "otherhigher" variable becomes zero. Than you are stuck in an infinite loop. To debug this, you would have to check when and why these conditions occur and try to solve the problem logcially. When it comes to debugging loops, the `show` primitive is your friend, as you can write current variable values, including the current turtle-id to the Command Center (e.g. `show otherhigher`).

Comment: As a suggestion for a more elegant solution, I would not use a while loop at all. I posted my solution as an answer below. You can use it or try to work on your own solution. Both should work.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution that follows a different kind of logic than yours. It does not actively transfer biomass from one turtle to the other, but processes all turtles on the same patch at once. However, from your question it is not clear what should happen, if there is more than one turtle with maximum biomass on a patch. Here I post two solutions. In the first attempt, one of these max biomass turtles would be chosen randomly and all other turtles on that patch would set their biomass to 0. In the second attempt, all turtles with max biomass would share the biomass of lower biomass turtles on the same patch.

Variant 1: Only one survivor on a patch with multiple turtles

```
ask turtles
[
 ;...
 ;some movement
 ;...

 if (any? other turtles-here)
 [
   ;; Only one turtle with max biomass would be chosen randomly, even if there is more than one
   ask max-one-of turtles-here [biomass]
   [
     set biomass (biomass + sum [biomass] of other turtles-here)

     ask other turtles-here
     [
       set biomass 0
     ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Variant 2: All turtles with maximum biomass survive and share the resources

```
ask turtles
[
 ;...
 ;some movement
 ;...

 if (any? other turtles-here)
 [
   ;We create two temporary agentsets, one with the surviving turtles and one with the consumed turtles
   let max-biomass-turtles turtles-here with-max [biomass]
   let low-biomass-turtles turtles-here with [not member? self max-biomass-turtles]

   ;Only if there are turtles to consume, calculate the share each max biomass turtle gets
   if (any? low-biomass-turtles)
   [
     let biomass-share (sum [biomass] of low-biomass-turtles / count max-biomass-turtles)

     ask max-biomass-turtles
     [
       set biomass (biomass + biomass-share)
     ]
     ask low-biomass-turtles
     [
       set biomass 0
     ]
    ]
  ]
]
```